# Firebase Custom Authentication - lastSignInTime = Null

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using 'firebase-admin' for node to create custom tokens based on users created using `admin.auth().createUser(params)` and updated via `admin.auth().updateUser(userId, updateParams)`

However, when a custom user is created, such user's "signed in" field is "null" in the Firebase Authentication Dashboard as well as when I fetch user record using `admin.auth().getUser('custom:uid').then((userRecord) => { console.log(userRecord.toJSON()); })`

Below is the result from fetching user record (I have masked credentials):

> {
> uid: 'custom:uid',
> email: 'xxx@yyy.com',
> emailVerified: false,
> displayName: 'testuser',
> photoURL: 'https://xxxx.jpg',
> phoneNumber: undefined,
> disabled: false,
> metadata: {
> **lastSignInTime: null,**
> creationTime: 'Mon, 29 Mar 2021 08:11:56 GMT'
> },
> passwordHash: undefined,
> passwordSalt: undefined,
> customClaims: undefined,
> tokensValidAfterTime: 'Mon, 29 Mar 2021 08:11:56 GMT',
> tenantId: undefined,
> providerData: []
> }

and below is my dashboard screenshot:
[image]

My question is what should I do to update 'lastSignInTime', so that it correctly updates upon a user sign in? I assumed that either when I `createUser()` or `updateUser()`, Firebase shall automatically record the "Signed In" field (as it did for "Created"), which it did not do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of "Signed In" will update when the user signs in for the first time.  As far as I'm aware there's no other way to update that value.

Comment: Thank you for the comment for me to realize that ```createUser()``` or ```updateUser()``` is not equivalent to "signed in".  I had to actually sign in using ```firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(customFirebaseToken)``` and retrieve UserCredential promise in order for Firebase Auth to update the "Signed In". Works now!